# html5 canvas kinetic textbox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I was wondering if there is a way for me to open up a textbox for users to type in on an onclick event? How would i go about making this? I'm thinking now that there may be a way for me to grab what the user types on a canvas and use the methods i've read about to output the text. Is this a possibility? But how would i allow the user to type on the canvas in the first place?

I've done a lot of reading and all the examples i could find were about simply outputting text onto the canvas rather than creating a textbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution - use Javascript's alert box. This will enable us to grab the text which the user wants to place on the screen. Then write the text where ever you want on the canvas (lots of tutorials on how to write text on a canvas).

Answer (score 4):

You have to literally make one, as in the onclick event fires and you do: `var myInput = document.createElement("textarea");`

You need to set the `myInput.style.width`, `height`, `top`, `left`, and of course the `myInput.style.position` to `"absolute"`, then position it where the user would expect.

Then you need to assign events to it. Maybe on keydown it will look for the Enter key, and if the enter key is pressed it will disappear and commit the text however you want it committed.

Then add it to the page.

Maybe it will do the same thing on a blur event (if the user clicks away).

Comment: +1 for your answer. I found a simple solution - just use javascripts alert box to get user input

Answer (score 2):

canvas is a bitmap image. You can't put an element "in it". You could put one hovering over it, though. What I think your looking for is the html5 [contenteditable attribute](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable).